# Cloning an SD card to another in Ubuntu using a single SD card reader

Tags: sd-card, clone

I have an SD card which has the image of Raspbian jessy for raspberry pi.

I currently have only a single SD card reader on my computer, and I would like to clone this SD card to another SD card only by using this reader.

Is there possibility to achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use dd and your harddrive. 
I will give an example:

For the backup (with your rasbian jessy sd card in the reader, but unmounted):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/home/bruni/backup.img
```

For the restore, after you have unmounted and replaced the sd card with a fresh one:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/bruni/backup.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

Of course you will first have to verify that mmcblk0 is your sd card (to do this compare the output of `df -h` before and after you insert the sd card) and replace bruni with your username.

I use the above for backing up my raspberry pi kodi installation.

PS: Neither copy nor rsync will lead to a bootable sd card, which is what you want.

Comment: I'd there a reason (besides speed) you opted to use a block size of 4mib?

Comment: I have tried bs=1M and bs=4M and did not see any differences other than speed. Here is a question on how to calculate optimal block size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161823/dd-how-to-calculate-optimal-blocksize, but as I said never had any problems with 4M and therefore did not see a reason to optimize this further.

Comment: will this work even if the replaced sd has a different size (for example, initial SD card 8GB, and I want to clone its content to a 16GB card because I am running out of space)?

Comment: @Zorglub29 It will work, but not as you intend. You will not gain the additional space. You will have wasted the additional 8GB.

Comment: Any way to get this to work with a larger SD card? Maybe I should open a new question?

Comment: @Zorglub29 A quick search https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/copy-current-sd-image-to-larger-sd-card Though, I have never tried this.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done on the Pi. Using Piclone the Raspberry Pi can back itself up to an SD.

Menu > Accessories > SD Card Copier

Select the SD the OS is running from in the top box and the backup card in the lower.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use existing tools with GUI.

So you can use the Raspberry Pi Imager for formatting and writing SD-Card-Images.

Regarding the creation of drive images (Laufwerksabbilder) you can simply use "gnome-disk-utility". There you can see the mounted drives on the left side, which you can easily select and identify the right drive which you want to image/clone.

The rest can be done via the menus (to the right) in the title bar.

So you only need a harddisk or SSD with the required space for the drive image.

Easy. You can use external USB-Drives. So it should be easy.

As far as I do remember "gnome-disk-utility" is not installed by default. But it is definitely worth to be installed when you have to clone drives.

Have fun. Time to drink a java.